# How to short this code or this true code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need in table change td when i click the button. I'm begginner in Jquery. I think to use this `document.createTextNode` In order to change the code in the table
.

Since I am a beginner, this will be correct or some differently correctly. Because table is so long and too code more

It's Example [many code in Jquery (Screnshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84yMx.png)

```js
$(".price-btn_1").click(function() {
  $( "td:eq(2)").empty().append(document.createTextNode("123") );
  $( "td:eq(3)").empty().append(document.createTextNode("456") );

  });
  

> when .price-btn_2 click change text in table td

$(".price-btn_2").click(function() {                          
  $( "td:eq(2)").empty().append(document.createTextNode("50") );
  $( "td:eq(3)").empty().append(document.createTextNode("30") )
  });
```

```css
.price-table tr td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="price-btn_all price-btn_1 active">iPhone 4</button>
<button class="price-btn_all price-btn_2">iPhone 4s</button>
    


    <table class="price-table">
     <thead>
     <tr>
     <td>bla1</td>
     <td>bla2</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>123</td>
     <td>456</td>
    </tr>
               </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery it is way more easy to accomplish your goal. Since you only want to set the text in the table cells, just use `text("123")` on the selection:

```
$("td:eq(2)").text("123");
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/

I must say that getting the tds just by their number in the document order is no good design. What if you decide to add another table before the first one? You would have to adjust all the numbers in your source code. Better use ids instead.

Answer (score 0):

### **Concept:**

1. Store your texts in a 2-dimensional array ([2d array](https://processing.org/tutorials/2darray/))
2. Loop through each `td` and set their text according to the index

   ```
   // keep the texts here
   var data = [
     ['table0#data0', 'table0#data1', 'table0#data2', 'table0#data3'],
     ['table1#data0', 'table1#data1', 'table1#data2', 'table1#data3'],
   ];

   $(".price-btn_1").click(function() {
     // loop through each <td>
     $(".price-table tbody td").each(function(n, el){
       // data[0] means table1
       // data[0][n] means nth data of table 1
       $(el).html(data[0][n]);
     });
   });

   $(".price-btn_2").click(function() {
     // loop through each <td>                         
     $(".price-table tbody td").each(function(n, el){
       // data[1] means table2
       // data[1][n] means nth data of table 2
       $(el).html(data[1][n]);
     });
   });
   ```

[jsbin snippet](https://jsbin.com/debedarovu/edit?html,js,output)

*Additional:*

- You don't really need to use `.empty().append()` when `.html()` does exactly the same thing. (If you're concern about performance, I don't think the difference could be *noticeable*)
- Selecting by only `$("td")` could be dangerous, imagine you have two tables on your page.

*Read more:*

[.each() method jquery](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

[javascript array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)